# Ruby method doesn't seem to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

I have a ruby script in which I would like to encapsulate variable initialization/reset in a method. I created the below method for variable resetting. 
But in irb, this method runs fine but when I print the variables after running the method like this: `initer`. It didnt do the job.

```
def intiter
  cntr = 0
  rec = 0
  timer = 0
end
```

Comment: How are you printing these variables? It should be very difficult to do so. I can't imagine a way to do it outside of `intiter`. And what job doesn't it do? And most importantly, what is your question?

Comment: `when I print the variables after running the method like this: initer. It didnt do the job.` means? be specific. your question is not clear. from where you call the method so that you didn't get the output?

Comment: You need to read up on basic variable scope and instance variables in Ruby. Those variables only exist inside the method, even if other ones with the same name exist elsewhere. Here's something I just Googled that looks like a good intro: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope

Comment: The rails community is famous for giving new people lots of flak when they ask decent but misguided questions. I hope for lots of upvotes your way and hope you never hear "you're doing it wrong" too many times. :)

Comment: I thought this was a good question, but I guess not. Scripting languages should allow this I thought but I guess I am going to have to involve classes

Comment: @user2081579 - pretty much everything in Ruby is an object. That includes the main routine of the script. So you could probably just stick an `@` in front of your variable names (to make them instance variables), or a `$` (to make them globals) but it is difficult to say for sure without seeing more of your script, or understanding more of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user2081579 This is a good question. Keep asking when things confuse you. Otherwise you'll never get further.

Comment: Definitely keep asking questions... but it'd help us to help you if you also added the code that calls this, and could think a bit more about what you mean when you say "It didnt do the job." - tells us: what you did to call the code (write it down, don't say in words), what the output was (copy and paste it, don't just say) and what you expected the output to be (again - write it down as though the code had worked). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method only sets local variables within the scope of `initer`; when that method ends, those variables that you set to `0` disappear into the ether. You need to be referencing class, instance, or global variables in order to set them from within your method. Class variables begin with `@@` and are shared by all instances of that class; instance variables begin with `@` and are accessible by anything within a particular instance of a class; globals begin with `$` and can be used from anywhere in the program, but can be subject to unexpected changes. Without knowing more code and what your overall design is, there's not much more I can help you with.

Edit: previous link I included wasn't to the correct section. Try http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html for more.

Also, [why's (poignant) guide to ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/media/poignant-guide.pdf) is good... if it's your cup of tea, anyway. I like it.

Comment: How do I create global variables I can use in a script? Like in bash?

Comment: Global variables in Ruby are preceded by `$`, as `$cntr` or `$timer`. These can be accessed from anywhere in your program. Use of globals is generally discouraged in favor of better architecture, but if it's a small program (or you are very mindful of them) they should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The `def` keyword begins a new `scope`, which means that any variables defined here are brand new and will be destroyed when the `end` keyword is hit. You are creating a brand new copy of those variables, setting them to 0, then destroying them. The original variables are never touched.